# Apache Avro aliases names with schema registry

Tags: avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to use aliases to rename filed name and generated java classes out of avro schema.  Producing the message with new name but my consumer application has old name OR aliases name in the schema. Getting exception while deserilaizing the message.

Producer Schema has:

```
        {
                            "name": "eventType",
                            "aliases": ["event"], <!-- oldname-->
                            "type": [
                                "null",
                                "string"
                            ]
                        },
```

Consumer Schema:

```
     {
                            "name": "event",
                             "type": [
                                "null",
                                "string"
                            ]
                        },
```

Error

```
 Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found com.Employee, expecting com.Employee, missing required field event
```

Comment: The schema registry isn't causing the problem. The avro parser simply expects the field, as the error says.

Answer (score 0):

The data was produced with `eventType`. Therefore, this is what the deserializer will try to use as a field name for generated types.

You need to add `"aliases": ["eventType"]` to `"name": "event"` for the deserializer to reuse the field on the consumer side.

Comment: Do I need add that in consumer schema ? I don’t have control on consumer applications..If one consumer want eventType and another consumer want it as event. How can we do that to produce the message to satisfy both consumer apps

Comment: Avro requires two schemas. It's the consumer (reader schema) that requires aliases to what the producer (writer schema) creates. Even if you have an alias, both field names should get resolved to the same value